# Fresh Jakarta EE project does not deploy on Payara 6

Tags: jakarta-ee, payara

I updated VS Code, installed Payara tools extension, created fresh new boilerplate Jakarta 10 EE project from https://start.jakarta.ee/. Then I successfully downloaded new Payara 6.2023.4 full server and imported it in VS Code, I started server and it runs. Then I opened folder in VS Code, it recognizes that it is Java project, I clicked on "Run on Payara Server", I get error in VS Code "workspace not found for [[object Object]]., source of this error is Payara Tools (Extension), server runs but only loads admin app. I don't know what I did wrong. I think they literally have bug in just running their boilerplate example on new Payara Server.

I downloaded Payara Micro, installed .war with Maven and deployed to Payara Micro and everything worked but that why I don't have Hot Reload and I don't want to wait 1min after every change to run Maven install and again Payara Micro.

[image]

I also managed to run it in Eclipse with Payara Micro config but Hot Reload also does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing my own batch script, running mvn install and then deploy --force that redeploys application without server restart.